# I'm trying to make a mastermind program

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a mastermind program but it keeps giving a "int" object is not subscriptable error.
Any help would be appreciated

This is the code I made

```
import random
num = random.randint(999,9999)

gnum = []
x = input("enter a 4 digit number")
gnum.append(x[0])
gnum.append(x[1])
gnum.append(x[2])
gnum.append(x[3])
correct = 0
for i in range(0,4):
  if num[i] == gnum[i]:
    correct += 1
print(num)
print(gnum)
```

Comment: `num` is an `int`. `[i]` on an `int` makes no sense. You want turn `num` into a string…?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this code produce the error 'int is not subscriptable'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596983/why-does-this-code-produce-the-error-int-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: You meant to turn num into a string: `num = str(random....)`. Also, note that the lower bound is included in `randint`, so your code might choose 999, which is only 3 digits long.

Comment: FWIW: `correct = sum(1 for a, b in zip(str(num), x) if a == b)` `print(num, x, correct)` That's your program compressed into a pythonic minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert integer to string. So you can simply change the `num` variable to `num = str(num)`.

```
import random
num = random.randint(999,9999)
num = str(num)
gnum = []
x = input("enter a 4 digit number ")
gnum.append(x[0])
gnum.append(x[1])
gnum.append(x[2])
gnum.append(x[3])
correct = 0
for i in range(0,4):
    if num[i] == gnum[i]:
        correct += 1
print(num)
print(gnum)
print(correct)
```

Comment: If you refer Python documentation you will find a much easier and more reliable method than this. Good luck.